# Angular ui.bootstrap pagination - current page not updating/watch not working

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-ui

I have a `pagination` inside a `dialog` both directives are of `ui.bootstrap`. The problem is that the `$watch` is not working for currentPage member.

Now, the similar code works perfectly fine for other pages where pagination is not inside some dialog.

I suppose this problem is related to `$scope` but then `currentPage` is available in the scope and i can display it on the template using `{{currentPage}}`

Please find the code in the [**plunker**](http://plnkr.co/edit/bam4QBZRIwRuXqhK8W0p?p=preview)

*`$scope.$watch('currentPage')` is not firing up on clicking page links.*

Now, for the workaround I could use callback `on-select-page` provided by the pagination directive.

e.g.

```
<pagination on-select-page="pageChanged(page)" total-items="totalItems" items-per-page = "numPerPage" page="currentPage" max-size="maxSize"></pagination>
```

and inside my controller i can have,

```
$scope.pageChanged = function(page) {
  console.log(page);    
};
```

But I rather need to understand why in such cases `$scope.$watch` wont work.

Update: 
From the console following is the watchers value

```
$$watchers: Array[1] 
0th: Object
  eq: false
  exp: "currentPage"
  fn: function (o,n){}
```

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Use:

```
... page="$parent.currentPage" ...
```

**Or proper solution:**

When nested scopes are involved bind your vars a level deeper i.e.:

```
$scope.data.currentPage = ...
```

details [here](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Understanding-Scopes)

example [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/2zY91RofKrmUf2zpMuPf?p=preview)

Comment: First of all,  I appreciate your effort for the answer. Thanks. Although this works. I have a question - if the scope is wrong how am I able to display currentPage on the template using `{{currentPage}}`. By the question I want to get better understanding of $scope. for the solution i could have used `on-select-page` attribute.

Comment: Forgive me for a working, but wrong answer, it's my 17th hour so far today and I'm usually prone to mistakes that late. The scope is correct, but when it's nested bind your vars a level deeper, i.e. $scope.data.currentPage and it will work just fine see https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Understanding-Scopes also see working example: http://plnkr.co/edit/2zY91RofKrmUf2zpMuPf?p=preview

Comment: "it's my 17th hour" >> no problem :) _"When nested scopes are involved bind your vars a level deeper"_ >> makes sense. thanks for clearing.

Comment: Thanks. First option worked for me. :)
..i have a question, why do you say the second solution is proper?

Comment: wrapping the pagination properties in to an object resolved the issue 

$scope.pagination = {  currentPage: 1, TotalPages : 1 , TotalCount : 10 };

Answer (score 1):

Because you're creating a new controller (ModalDialogBaseCtl) inside the TestCtrl controller, Angular will create a new scope, which inherits all properties from its parent.

The line that looks suspect to me is where you're assigning a value to $scope.currentPage at the start of ModalDialogBaseCtrl.  Angular will interpret this as you declaring a new variable called currentPage in the new scope.  However, your pagination control is attached to the currentPage variable in MainCtrl so watching the ModalDialogBaseCtl one does nothing (it never changes value).

One fix is to use $parent as Max suggests, but that is not a great structure.  Instead, try to find a way to only have one currentPage property instead of two.

Comment: Thanks for answering firstly. _"creating a new controller...will create a new scope"_ >> I am aware of this fact. _"I am assigning a value to $scope.currentPage at the start of  Ctrl"_ >> even without this result is same. _"try to find a way to only have one currentPage property instead of two."_ >> well I cant think of a solution here, *I have a master list displayed using `TestCtrl` that uses `currentPage` so I cant remove it from there*. May be you can suggest something here. I agree on its not a great structure if I must use `$parent` to access any $scope object